# How to highlight the concept of degree of separation?

Tags: usability, user-expectation

I own an application aiming to organize meetings between users that may know each other.

For instance, Bob creates a meeting, and Alice then notices it. 
Alice expects the application to inform her about the nature of the relationship to Bob.

For example: 
Bob is linked to you by two degrees : friend's friend.

Sounds good, but I consider the term "degree" as being too "cold", too "technical".

What may be a better way to highlight this concept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go with an approach similar to how Linkedin and Facebook do it. Linkedin recommends people with regards to how many common connections they have as shown below

[image]

The screenshot above also shows the degree of connection since it establishes if the person is directly connected or connected through a friend or connected through a friend of a friend. This might be an approach you can look at if you look at expanding the linked in tree structure below.

Facebook has a similar approach as well

[image]

Linkedin actually takes a level forward where they allow you to see who are the common connections (well facebook does that as well but I like this tree structure as it establishes the common connection points)

[image]

Comment: LinkedIn also _literally_ shows the degree of connection, which is visible in your screenshot. That's what the "2nd" and "3rd" are. Suggest you add this to your answer.